# High speed TTL pulse generation

Tags: gpio, memory, output

I'd like to take ~400 MB binary file, where 0's indicate low and 1's indicate high, and stream this out the rPi I/O with 20 ns time base.

So something like `0000101001`

Would yield

```
Low Low Low Low Hi Low Hi Low Low Hi
```

over 200 ns.

It seems like [this dma demo](https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-gpio-dma-demo) might suggest it's possible?

If not possible, I'm also open to hearing what piece of hardware/system would allow me to do this.

Comment: I feel your question is an interesting one, but also a mixture of shopping request and opinion. I'd suggest you contact the author of the GitHub repo you referenced, and pose your questions to him. FWIW, I'll opine that it certainly ***appears*** credible.

Comment: In this case the poster is really asking for *what kind* of hardware, which is fine -- it would have to be USB based as that's the only bus that will transfer that fast (~128 MB/sec) from userspace.  And even that is probably iffy, plus you'd probably have to load it into memory first since you're unlikey to have read speeds from storage like that.  I think this is pushing the bounds too far, the Pi is not the right device.